# JavaFX webview, JQuery

Tags: jquery, javafx, webview

How to know in javaFX code when and what response has been sent by JQuery?
We have ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        username: $('#').val(),
        password: $('#').val()
      },
success: function (data) {//need to know data in JavaFX code }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment to clarify the question but if you want to embed javascript code in your application you can with [webEngine.executeScript()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-) method and you can event [execute jquery](https://community.oracle.com/message/10446280).

You can also add state listeners where you do your handling.

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
  new ChangeListener < State > () {
    @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
      if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        System.out.println("Succes");
      }

    }
  });
```

You can also fetch data with [DataFX](http://www.javafxdata.org/) library which can be parsed into JavaFX observable properties. Example if you were to populate a Tab with tweets:

```
 private void populateTab(Tab tab) {
   try {
     XmlConverter converter = new XmlConverter("item", Tweet.class);
     RestSource dr = new RestSource("http://search.twitter.com", converter);
     dr.setPath("search.rss?q=javafx");
     ListObjectDataProvider < Tweet > sodp = new ListObjectDataProvider(dr);
     sodp.retrieve(); //This retrieves the data.

     final ListProperty < Tweet > op = sodp.getData(); //Your data here.
     ListView lv = new ListView(op.get());
     tab.setContent(lv);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     //Handle exception
   }
 }
```